# Why declare a copy of a private field as `final`

Tags: java, oop, final

In *[Efficient Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)* Joshua Bloch writes:

> Note that a nonzero-length array is always mutable, so it is wrong for
>   a class to have a public static final array field, or an accessor that
>   returns such a field. If a class has such a field or accessor, clients
>   will be able to modify the contents of the array. This is a frequent
>   source of security holes:

```
// Potential security hole!
public static final Thing[] VALUES = { ... };
```

> Beware of the fact that many IDEs generate accessors that return
>   references to private array fields, resulting in exactly this problem.
>   There are two ways to fix the problem. You can make the public array
>   private and add a public immutable list:

```
private static final Thing[] PRIVATE_VALUES = { ... };
public static final List<Thing> VALUES =
Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(PRIVATE_VALUES));
```

> Alternatively, you can make the array private and add a public method
>   that returns a copy of a private array:

```
private static final Thing[] PRIVATE_VALUES = { ... };
public static final Thing[] values() {
    return PRIVATE_VALUES.clone();
}
```

And my question is:

- Why bother with returning a `final` variable - if it's just a copy ?

After all, in cases where the user *wants* to modify it (for her/his own use) we're actually forcing her/him to create another non-final copy, which doesn't make sense.

Comment: OK I think I see what you are saying. You are asking why bother returning, say, an unmodifiable list as opposed to `int[] ret = new int[sce.length]; System.arraycopy(sce, 0, ret, 0, sce.length); return ret;`? Which is mutable for the receiver but does not refer to the original field that you do not want modified.

Comment: In cases like this I like Guava's `Immutable*` classes; compact, high-performance, immutable.

Comment: @Radiodef yes - that's exactly what I meant! and Boann provided a good answer - that's not a *copy* of the original list, just a "view" that restricts write access. When I read the docs I missed the meaning of "view"...

Comment: I also do think it's an interesting question.

Comment: @Radiodef but now it makes sense. returning a "view" should be inexpensive comparing to copying the list. It "saves" the copying actions - and passes the responsibility to the user if she/he wants/needs to do it.

Comment: @alfasin Yup. It's a nice technique because it creates collections that apparently contain a lot of data, yet they have marginal creation cost because they store virtually nothing and avoid unneeded copying. On the other hand, wrappers always have a smidgin more overhead on every access, because each accessor method has to pass the call forward to the corresponding method on the wrapped object.  Of course, if performance of access to the returned object is critical, it's still possible for to call `toArray()` on it or otherwise create a more direct copy of the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Arrays.asList` wraps the original array. It doesn't copy the data. `Collections.unmodifiableList` also wraps the original list rather than copying the data.

That's why you're returning an `unmodifiableList` wrapper, because otherwise, changes made to the list returned by `Arrays.asList` would write through to the original private array.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question! I thought that it creates a *copy* of the original list - my bad.

Comment: So in other words returning an unmodifiableList circumvents the need to copy the list at all. (Assuming the receiving method only needs to read from it.)

Answer (score 5):

This isn't returning a `final` object -- it's just declaring the method as non-overridable.  There's no such thing as a `final` object -- only a final variable (reference or primitive), a final method, and a final class.

Comment: I meant a final variable (unmodifiableList). My bad. Why to return an immutable object and Why shouldn't we override this method ?

Comment: It's not that you shouldn't, it's that you can't.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I didn't understand your comment. I re-edit the question so it'll be clearer.

Comment: @alfasin Technically speaking you can't really return a final variable because only the value is returned. Louis is saying that the final keyword in a method declares the method as non-overridable, it doesn't refer to the return value. In the code example, final just happens to appear before the return type. It could just as easily be `final public static Thing[] values()`. One might declare a method as final for all kinds of reasons.

Comment: @Radiodef I used the wrong term to describe an immutable object. I wrote it in the first comment and also re-edited the question.

Comment: @alsafin the _method_ is declared final, in accordance with another item of the same book: `Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it`

Comment: @alfasin sorry, I can't delete it now, but it was completely valid before you edited your question, you had a method declared as final...